# Does Clickhouse take the amount of free disk space when scheduling background merges?

Tags: clickhouse

I have a Clickhouse cluster (three nodes) that contains a Merge Tree table, and Aggregating Merge Tree and a materialized view that fills the aggregating merge tree with data we insert in the merge tree. All tables are present on each node. (see the full schema in this gist [here](https://gist.github.com/fpacifici/733f6d32e4a1b355f2451f6009b03f07)).

I recently increased the storage size (from 4TB per node to 4.5TB) and I noticed that right after that Clickhouse seemed to have become more aggressive at running background merges. It seems to run longer merges with higher rows merged per second rate, to the point that some merge impacts the IO bandwidth of the servers with negative effects on the insertion rate.

I noticed this setting [here](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/merge-tree-settings/#max-bytes-to-merge-at-max-space-in-pool). It mentions that Clickhouse would schedule a merge if there are enough free resources in the background pool.

Does anybody know if that takes into account the amount of disk space? More space -> more likely to run merges that would create bigger partitions? The value we use for that parameter is the default one. And I noticed indeed that the biggest active partitions we have are around 150GB though I cannot say how big they were before adding storage.

Please let me know if there is any additional context needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, CH merge scheduler takes into account the amount of free disk space.
150GB merge able to start only if 300GB+ free disk space available.